# Django Forms: Showing only the first error in template?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am currently using Django's built in login view, with a form for users to log in, and have something along the lines of:

`{% if form.username.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.username.errors }}</p>{% endif %}`

for each field. I would like to move all the error messages maybe into a tool tip or all to the top of the login box, so I want to show only the first error message. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As with any list-like object, you can use the `first` template filter:

```
{{ form.username.errors|first }}
```

Comment: I meant to ask the first error in general, including non-field errors. So if there is an error in username AND in password, I just want to show whichever comes first in form.errors?

Comment: {{form.username.errors|first}} would only show the first error relate to user, and form.errors|first does not seem to work ):